# What is the right way to move references around in my output folder?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, post-build-event

My solution contains a few default Plugin projects which our build into

```
<OutputPath>..\bin\Debug\Plugins\$(MSBuildProjectName)</OutputPath>
```

Doing that all referencec assemblies end up in the same folder as my project assembly.
I would like to have them in

```
..\bin\Debug\Plugins\$(MSBuildProjectName)\Dependencies\
```

I successfully did by moving the dlls around from the post-build event command line.

Is this the right way? Or what should I do instead?

Comment: @JonasH sorry but if you't read my post again you would probably realize that I say where my files are now and where I want to have some of them instead. what should a file tree add to this? also I'm not here to discuss the necessity or sufficiency of it. I just want to know if there is a better ( official ) way to achieve that.
I want my plugin folders to be organized. I'm sure you can solve this in MSBuild somehow without having to run robocopy from a post-build event

Comment: Any update of this? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this the right way? Or what should I do instead?

I think this is already the correct way, because no matter what method you using, you still needs to move/copy the files in this situation.

Just meet your requirement is ok.